# Data Binding doesn't update a value

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I am playing around with data binding, i create a user control (view) like this:

```
<UserControl>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
      Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" 
      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelSampleDataSource}}"
      >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Var1, Mode=TwoWay}" InputScope="Number" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="90"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Var2}" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="90" />
</Grid>
```

I have this class Model

```
 public class ModelSample:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ModelSample()
    {

    }

    private double var1;
    public double Var1
    {
        get { return var1; }
        set 
        { 
            var1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("var"); 
        }
    }

    private double var2;
    public double Var2
    {
        get { return var2; }
        set 
        { 
            var2 = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("var2"); 
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

and this is the ViewModel

```
public class ViewModelSample
{
    private static ModelSample model=new ModelSample();
    public static ModelSample Model
    {
        get { return model; }
        set { model = value; }
    }

}
```

My problem is : when i change the value of var1 (using the textbox) i want to update the value of var2, how can i do it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string values you use for OnPropertyChanged must match the property names instead of the field names. After fixing simply changing Var2 from inside Var1's setter should do the trick.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to mark it as answer if your beleive it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
    private double var1;
public double Var1
{
    get { return var1; }
    set 
    { 
        var1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("var"); 
    }
}

private double var2;
public double Var2
{
    get { return var2; }
    set 
    { 
        var2 = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("var2"); 
    }
}
```

to this

```
    private double var1;
public double Var1
{
    get { return var1; }
    set 
    { 
        var1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Var"); 
    }
}

private double var2;
public double Var2
{
    get { return var2; }
    set 
    { 
        var2 = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("Var2"); 
    }
}
```

Raising property changed must be **case sensitive** on its property name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private double var1;
public double Var1
{
    get { return var1; }
    set 
    { 
        var1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Var1"); 
    }
}

private double var2;
public double Var2
{
    get { return var2; }
    set 
    { 
        var2 = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("Var2"); 
    }
}
```

Note that the OnPropertyChanged string has to match the Property's name